# How to access custom JSON file in shopify at liquid file level

Tags: json, shopify, liquid

I know it is possible to access a JSON file at the JavaScript level on the front end, but is it possible to access a JSON file and its contents in `/assets/` folder (or elsewhere if need be) at the Liquid level?

I was hoping for something like

> `{{ '/assets/some_file.json.liquid' | example_object.inner_object.some_key }}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

During server-side rendering, `Shopify` turns Liquid into a massive string, and sends that across the wire as browser food. HTML, CSS and JS.

If you have an asset foo.js containing JSON, you can indeed render that to the client, as

```
{{ 'foo.js' | asset_url }}
```

But you cannot use the JSON itself to steer any kind of server-side rendering. You can embed Liquid tags in your JS file and name it foo.js.liquid, and anything in your Liquid will affect the render, but then why bother with the JSON part?

If you are so interested in special Liquid rendering, setup your theme to render with settings and their values.

Alternatively, once the JSON downloads to the client, you are free to monkey around with pure JS to achieve glory.

Comment: Good answer, thank you!  Can you elaborate on this: "You can embed Liquid tags in your JS file and name it foo.js.liquid, and anything in your Liquid will affect the render"?  Do you mean I can make "liquid 'JSON-like' objects" stored in an `/assets/` file, which I can then use to steer server side logic? What documentation do I look for on how to do this -- I've tried all kinds of phrases but I just keep arriving at regular liquid documentation which I don't find helpful for this?

Comment: you cannot affect rendering with JSON, but with settings. You need to examine the settings.json file in your shopify theme. Anything you put in there does AFFECT the rendering.

Answer (score 0):

I got here in a search for ability to fetch and process a JSON file that attached to the Collection through metafield, unfortunatelly accepted solution didn't worked for me returning error.

The code below worked:
`{{collection.metafields.my_fields.fieldname.value.url}}`

the ending `.value.url` is returning full path to the JSON file that is attached via metafields